# Glitch on collapse pubcenter

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, monogame

I'm building a game using monogame and I'm using the pubcenter SDK to show advertisements. Everything goes fine, untill the adcontrol can't load an advertisement and tries to collapse. When it does that my game will glitch for a second. Is there a way to prevent that glitch?

Regards,

Tom